# sharp inequality ? an application of Taylor-Lagrange formula

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\subset\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^2$ function and let $M$ be an upper bound for $|f''|$.

It's asked to prove, using Taylor-Lagrange formula (or otherwise), that

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx - (b-a)f\left(\dfrac{a+b}{2}\right)\right| \le \dfrac{M}{24}(b-a)^3$$

any hints / advice are welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without loss of generality, we may assume that $a = -h$ and $b = h$ where $h > 0$. Thus we need to show that
$$\left|\int_{-h}^{h}f(x)\,dx - 2hf(0)\right| \leq \frac{M}{3}h^3.$$
This is easy to accomplish using Taylor's theorem: for any $x \in [-h, h]$,
$$f(x) = f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(\theta(x)x)}{2}x^2,$$
where $\theta(x) \in (0, 1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: \begin{equation}f(x_0 +h) = f(x_0)+ f'(x_0)h + O(h^2)\tag{1}\end{equation}

Try finding a good value for $x_0$, then substitute this equation into the integral $$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ and evaluate the LHS of your inequality. You will need a more precise form of $(1)$ (Using Taylor's Theorem) to actually show the desired inequality.